# What is the URL description in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to know the definition of the URL in sugarCRM.

### localhost/sugarcrm/index.php?module=Users&action=Login

From the above URL I know the module is "Users" but what is that action?. When I clicking the login button in login page, where the action will go and what is the file name to check username and the password?

Is there any way to check where the control is going?. That is wich file is containing the code. We can inspect HTML element in the browser by using firebug. Like that, can we check where the login button functionalities have written?.

Answer (score 1):

The action can be defined in it's own file in the module. This is the case with users. The `Login` action refers to `modules/Users/Login.php`.

Actions can also be defined in a controller i.e. `modules/Administrator/controller.php`. In this example there is a `action_savetabs` method which creates a `savetabs` action.

Note that custom action files or custom controllers may add or override actions so you will also want to check `custom/modules/TheModule/` for these.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'll only add a few common examples. Most modules have actions for 'index' which is synonymous with 'ListView' - as well as separate actions for 'EditView' and 'DetailView'. Occasionally you'll find the endpoint of index.php, but if you watch the HTTP Requests you'll the action is specified in POST instead of in GET.